# tinymce : textarea not return value in servlet at form submission

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, servlets, tinymce

In servlet ,  when accessing values of textarea   which is set via tinymce ` through

> String desc = req.getParameter("desc");

`return no value. But the value can access through Java Script via

```
> var content =  tinymce.get('motherdesc');
>       alert(content.getContent());
```

The jsp file is given below:

> ```
> <!--For WYSWYG texteditor -->
> <script type="text/javascript" src="/tinymce/tinymce.min.js"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>   tinymce.init({
>       selector : "textarea",
>       menubar : false,
>       plugins : "textcolor",
>       toolbar : "undo redo | styleselect | bold italic  | forecolor "
>   });
> </script>
>
> <textarea name="desc" id="motherdesc" style="margin-bottom: 10px;"></textarea>
> ```

Comment: Is this textarea in form and you are submitting the form or you are making ajax call?

Comment: If you are doing a form submit, make sure your `textarea` is inside the `form` element .

Comment: @RaviKumar the textarea is inside form tag and it is form submission, not ajax call